# Do we use present perfect or past perfect when talking about repeated actions in the past?

Tags: grammar, present-perfect, past-perfect

I have a short query -

Which of the following is the correct variant?

"...just try to remember how many times you were angry that a new episode of your favorite series hasn’t been translated into Russian yet, although it was released a week ago.

or...

"...just try to remember how many times you were angry that a new episode of your favorite series hadn’t been translated into Russian yet, although it was released a week ago.

Kind of undecided here.

What are the specific grammar rules which govern cases like this?

I would be really grateful for your help.

Comment: The second version is *almost* correct, but not quite. It should be " . . . just try to remember how many times you **were** angry that a new episode of your favourite series **hadn't** been translated into Russian yet, although it ***had been*** released a week ***before***." You need to remember to change the tenses in the final part of the sentence as well.

Answer (score 1):

The second version is almost correct, but not quite. It should be "...just try to remember how many times you were angry that a new episode of your favorite series **hadn't** been translated into Russian yet, although it **had been** released a week **before**." You need to remember to change the tenses in the final part of the sentence as well.
  The problem with "a week ago", is that means "a week before now". Here, you don't mean "a week before now".  You mean "a week before (a year ago)."

> What are the specific grammar rules which govern cases like this?

The past perfect is a way to recount a story which occurred in the past, and talk about events that happened even earlier.